# Create copy of Word document then continue editing the document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to make a copy of my document whenever I hit a shortcut key, then continue with the original document. The copy should be in the same directory as my document, but with name modified by a date/time string.

This code creates the appropriate named file in the appropriate directory, but when opened the saved document contains no content and shows "Word" as the title.

```vb
Sub Checkpoint()

Dim SplitFullName() As String
Dim ThisFullName As String
Dim CopyFileName As String
Dim CopyDoc As Document
Dim DateTimeString As String

    ThisFullName = ActiveDocument.FullName
    
    SplitFullName = Split(ThisFullName, ".", 2) ' Split filename at the dot
    DateTimeString = Format(Now(), "yymmddhhmmss")
    CopyFileName = SplitFullName(0) & " " & DateTimeString & "." & SplitFullName(1)
    
    Selection.WholeStory ' I want to select and copy the entire current document
    Selection.Copy
                        ' Create new open document with curent document as template
    Set CopyDoc = Documents.Add(ActiveDocument.FullName) ' Copy document now active
    Selection.Paste
    ' at this point the copy document is visible on screen
    ' with the right content and name in heading
    
    CopyDoc.SaveAs2 (CopyFileName)      '   Save the copy with date/time in filename
    CopyDoc.Close          ' and close and remove the copy document

End Sub
```

Comment: The simplest, and most obvious approach, would be to 1) save the changes to your current document; 2) use SaveAs on your current document to create the checkpoint; 3) close the checkpoint document; 4) re-open the original document. This process will give you an exact copy of your document, something you cannot achieve using copy and paste as it will not include items such as headers and footers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Filesystem Object to copy an open file.

```vb
Public Sub Checkpoint()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

Dim CopyFileName As String
With ActiveDocument
    .Save
    CopyFileName = getFileNameWithoutExtension(.Name) & " " & Format(Now(), "yymmddhhmmss") & "." & getFileExtensionFromFilename(.Name)
    fso.CopyFile .FullName, .Path & "\" & CopyFileName
End With


End Sub

Private Function getFileNameWithoutExtension(ByVal Filename As String) As String
    getFileNameWithoutExtension = Left(Filename, InStrRev(Filename, ".") - 1)
End Function


Private Function getFileExtensionFromFilename(ByVal Filename As String) As String
    getFileExtensionFromFilename = Right(Filename, Len(Filename) - InStrRev(Filename, "."))
End Function
```

Regarding your method to retrieve the new filename: it won't work if you use a dot within the filename. It is safer to use `InStrRev` which looks for the first dot from right to left - which will be the dot separating the extension from the base name.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to save the newly created file as macro enabled file ((.docm))?
You can use the 'docx' extension for the newly created file.

```
CopyFileName = SplitFullName(0) & " " & DateTimeString & "." & "docx"
```

Comment: That approach, of course, will add multiple instances of DateTimeString if the document being processed is the one that was created in the previous iteration...